# CKEditor handling of PDFs with "image" button on toolbar

Tags: pdf, ckeditor

One of my users innocently specified a `.PDF` file as the target file when embedding an "image" using the appropriate toolbar button. Much to our surprise, CKEditor produced an `<img>` tag, which the ever-dutiful browser handled by rendering *(only ...)* page #1 of the PDF, *as an image!*

Well – I want it to be smarter than that.  If the "image" is actually a PDF, I want the HTML tag to be something that embeds the PDF content in a way that you can page through it – say, as Facebook does.

Those of you with lots-and-lots of CKEditor experience, what would you recommend?  After all, what the user did is perfectly reasonable . . .

Comment: Uhh, "how do I do that?"  ... **:-)** (Message me privately. Yeah, I use _SE_ but I don't get too deep into it.)

Comment: Ahh, thank you.  Never been there.  Never.  Now, let me see...  Oh, goo grief, like I have the time to go back and click a bunch of check-box icons now?  I got better things to do ... like, produce better results for my customers, hopefully using _SE_ as a resource to get there.  Otherwise, _SE's_ gonna just have to take care of itself.